# SSRS - Javascript Report load event

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, dom-events

I'm embedding a Report into an iframe (the report is fetched with .NET ReportingServices)

I'd like to launch a Javascript function once the report is loaded.

I tried:

```
window.addEventListener("load", ...)
```

But as the report result is loaded with Javascript, `window.load` is triggered before the report is effectively loaded.

Are there some Javascript functions exposed that would allow me to handle the report load? Like:

```
the_report.loaded(function () {
  alert(document.height);
});
```

By the way the aim is to get the final rendered document height.

Comment: In case you hadn't found it yet: here's [the MSDN reference for client side ReportViewer programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405(VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript support is minimal at best. Sadly these controls are still behind with the times on most fronts. You can find what is exposed and documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405(VS.100).aspx

Luckily for you there is a get_isLoading() function you can call:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756413(v=vs.100).aspx

Try something like this:

```
(function() {

    var onLoad = function() {
       // Do something...
    };
    var viewerReference = $find("ReportViewer1");

    setTimeout(function() {
        var loading = viewerReference.get_isLoading();

        if (!loading) onLoad(); 
    },100);

})();
```

Comment: Ok I see it's quite limited indeed. `viewerReference` will be very useful for me. I will also use a flag to trigger the "event" only once :) I'll try that and tell you. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JussiPalo A special function provided by SSRS to find report viewer controls based on ID.

Answer (score 3):

Here is exactly what I ended up with (iframe side)

```
/* This will run only when all ReportingService JS is loaded */
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    /* Let's consider the report is already loaded */
    loaded = true;
    /* The function to call when the report is loaded */
    var onLoad = function () {
        alert(document.body.scrollHeight);
        /* Set the report loaded */
        loaded = true;
    };
    /* The report instance */
    var viewerReference = $find("ReportViewer1");

    /* The function that will be looped over to check if the report is loaded */
    check_load = function () {
        var loading = viewerReference.get_isLoading();
        if (loading) {
            /* It's loading so we set the flag to false */
            loaded = false;
        } else {
            if (!loaded) {
                /* Trigger the function if it is not considere loaded yet */
                onLoad();
            }
        }
        /* Recall ourselves every 100 miliseconds */
        setTimeout(check_load, 100);
    }

    /* Run the looping function the first time */
    check_load();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Pierre's solution, I ended up with this. (Simplified to have it only call until it loaded once, since it seemed to run after every load)

Note: my report configuration was SizeToReportContent="true" AsyncRendering="false", so that might be part of why I could simplify it.

```js
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    var viewerReference = $find("ReportViewer1");
    check_load = function () {
        if (viewerReference.get_isLoading()) {
            setTimeout(check_load, 100);
        } else {
            window.parent.ReportFrameLoaded();
        }
    }
    check_load();
});
```